# why i += 1 changes to i += 2 works?

Tags: python, while-loop

It's my first time to ask a question here.

I try to get players whose height is above 200 centimeters but I don't know why it doesn't work until I adjust `i += 1` to `i += 2`, and I still don't know why it works.

By the way, I try to use `while` loops but not `for` loops to write this code.

Thanks in advance!

```
players = [['James', 202],
           ['Curry', 193],
           ['Durant', 205],
           ['Jordan', 199],
           ['David', 211]]

i = 0
while i < len(players):
    if players[i][1] < 200:
        continue
    print(players[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: If `players[i][1] < 200` then you go into an infinite loop because you never change the value of i and it's always at the same item. The reason it works with +=2 is that if you do that you are skipping the only list item that falls into that category.

Comment: @SamB `i` will always be 1, `i < len(players)` will always be True and the loop will run forever.

Comment: @SamB more specifically, once `i==1` the `if` is true and executes `continue` so the `i+=1` never executes again.

Comment: agreed, took my comments back

Comment: `for player in players:` is more pythonic and would prevent this type of error.

Comment: Why do not you use a cycle?

Comment: I have been programming for a long time and never ever use while loop in any programming language because they are just very illogical to me. "for" loops are most straight forward logical loops to write, execute and understand. Just my 2 cents

Comment: I'm so grateful to you for actually solving my mystery, appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restructure with a `for` loop and specify only when you want to do something:

```
players = [['James', 202], ['Curry', 193], ['Durant', 205],
           ['Jordan', 199], ['David', 211]]

for p, height in players:
    if height >= 200:
        print(p)

# James
# Durant
# David
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
[p for p, height in players if score >= 200]
# ['James', 'Durant', 'David']
```

The problem with your code is that when it hits `continue`, `i` does not increment as the next iteration of the loop begins. [Read up on `continue` here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). Here's how you would do it with a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(players):
    p, height = players[i]
    if height >= 200:
        print(p)
    i += 1

# James
# Durant
# David
```

Comment: `for player, height in players`** I'd say is the best

Comment: Agreed `for` loop is better but OP wants to "try to use while loops but not for loops to write this code".

Comment: @Alex I find it very strange when people try to use something less efficient and less readable for a simple task as for/while. Nevertheless, you have a valid point.

Comment: I have added the `while` version for good measure. since OP is a learner, it's good to see / understand all methods.

Comment: @AntonvBR maybe OP is trying to learn how to use `while` loops. Even if this is not the case it is helpful to explain why code is not working.

Comment: thank you guys for helping me out, I was trying to use different ways to write this. But actually, for loops is way more better to use :D

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you end up in an infinite loop due to the following bit of code:

```
if players[i][1] < 200:
    continue  # here you skip to the top of the loop without changing i
```

When you change to `i += 2` this problem still exists but you happen to avoid getting stuck in it. This is because you only process the even-indexed elements. Each of these has a value over `200` so your code never gets to the `continue` statement.

```
[['James', 202],
 ['Durant', 205],
 ['David', 211]]
```

Try:

```
i = 0
while i < len(players):
    if players[i][1] < 200:
        print(players[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using while loop here is another, clean, alternative:

```
players = [['James', 202],
           ['Curry', 193],
           ['Durant', 205],
           ['Jordan', 199],
           ['David', 211]]

while players:
    p, height = players.pop(0)
    if height >= 200:
        print(p)
```

This works because players evaluates to false when it is empty `[]`. And in every step we are popping away an item. However, after running the loop, players is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding  i += 1 to i += 2 and not understanding what it means just think what you are trying to do.

You want to get values from the array right? i.e.

```
players[0][1] will get you 202
players[1][1] will get you 193
players[2][1] will get you 205
....
```

So increment i accordingly.

Sometimes the easiest way to write code is to first say out loud in your head or write it in simple english.

- You want to loop over values of the array
- You want to then check if the value matches something
- If it does print it
- If it doesn't don't print it and then move on to the next value
- Keep doing it till you have checked every value in the array

Now writing code makes sense right?

The easiest way to understand increment is to write it like this

```
i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to achieve what you're after in the future

```
players = [['James', 202],
           ['Curry', 193],
           ['Durant', 205],
           ['Jordan', 199],
           ['David', 211]]

for name,height in players:
    if height>=200: print(name)
```